# Two questions about the enumerate enviroment: getting rid of the dot and using enumeration by Greek letters

Tags: enumerate

How do I get rid off the dot "." after i.,ii.,iii.,iv.,etc?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem,bbding,etoolbox,calc}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item abc
\item 123
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Next question, how do I force the enumerate environment to count by the Greek alphabet,i.e. instead of i. `$\alpha$`, instead of ii. `$\beta$`, etc.?

Comment: Use `\begin{enumerate}[i]` with `enumerate` package.

Answer (score 3):

Use the package [`moreenum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moreenum) to get greek numbering. And since you're using `enumitem` anyway, instead of:

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
```

Try:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\greek*]
```

at each numbered list you want to be labeled with greek letters, or if you want to change it globally, use

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\greek*}
```

in the preamble. The `*` after `\greek` is part of the `enumitem` syntax, and signifies that the value of the enumeration counter is used, see section 3.1 of the `enumitem` documentation for more details on the label syntax, and section 5 for details on global enumerate settings.

Comment: It works, but                                                    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\greek{enumi}} has the same problem as stated in my first question: it puts dots "." after $alpha$,$beta$,etc.How to suppress these dots??

Comment: Yes, the alternative works fine, without a dot.But then I must specify at every point with \begin{enumerate} also the label=\greek*.I wanted to do this generally at the beginning of the document, once for all.

Comment: BTW. why greek in label ends with a star "*"?

Comment: Setlist does not work:                                                               \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{enumitem,bbding,etoolbox,calc,moreenum}

    
    \setlist[enumerate]{label=\greek*}
                                                                \begin{document}                                                  \setlist[enumerate]{label=\greek*}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item abc
    \item 123
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}

Comment: The code in your comment works fine for me. Are you getting an error or is the output not what you want?

Comment: It gives me "1. abc
2. 123" i.e. no greek letters and even with a dot after.

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with your latex distribution or some package is outdated. It might be worth asking as a separate question.

Comment: But when I compile it from the command line, instead from WinEdt, it works fine. So it's not fault of the code itself.